# Verifying the access token received from Google OAuth 2.0 API server-side with Java

Tags: java, spring, google-oauth

I am currently exploring the possibility of signing our users in using the Google Identity platform.

My client-side developed in React loads the Javascript library and receives an access-token using my client-id which i created in the Google Cloud. The code for this can be seen here:

```
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="CLIENT ID HERE"
         data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/test"
         data-prompt_parent_id="g_id_onload"
         style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 550px;
            width: 0; height: 0; z-index: 1001;"
         data-context="signup">
    </div>
```

After clicking the login button generated by this library, the access token is sent to my back-end endpoint (http://localhost:8080/test) for verification and to extract the payload from the JWT. The code for this can be seen here:

```
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(HttpServletRequest req, @CookieValue("g_csrf_token") String cookie) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        GooglePublicKeysManager manager = new GooglePublicKeysManager(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory());

        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(manager)
                // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("CLIENT ID HERE"))
                // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
                //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
                .build();

        if(req.getParameter("g_csrf_token") == null){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("No CSRF token in body.");
        }

        if(cookie == null){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("No CSRF token in header.");
        }

        if(!Objects.equals(req.getParameter("g_csrf_token"), cookie)){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Failed to verify double submit cookie.");
        }

        // this is the JWT token received from the client-side
        String credentials = req.getParameter("credential");

        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(credentials);
        if (idToken != null) {
            Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

            // Print user identifier
            String userId = payload.getSubject();
            System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

            // Get profile information from payload
            String email = payload.getEmail();
            boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
            String name = (String) payload.get("name");
            String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
            String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
            String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
            String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

            System.out.println(name);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Login Success!");
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me if this is the right and secure way to implement this? This setup is working, and the token is verified and the payload is extracted, but i worry about the security.
I am finding the google documentation very messy and i am new to using their API's.

Comment: remember access token is authorization Oauth2.  Not Signin Open id connect Id token.  I think your mixing your terms.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to verifiy an access token is to use it.  Send a request to the api of your choice and if you don't have access it will tell you.

Id tokens are from open id connection and a respose to a user sign in call. It requires an id token. You can only get payload on an id token as it is a jwt. am access token is not a jwt, it has no user claims to verfy.

Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

Comment: Alright, i see that i have mixed some of my terms. So to make this clear;
The access-token is used to access any Google API's of choice (in this case the userInfo API?)  as long as the access token contains that scope?

Comment: the user info endpoint is technically an api endpoint yes but if you want profile information you should go through the people api it is more reliable.  you only need to profile or openid scope unless you want email address then add the email scope